# Convert one javascript nested object data structure to nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, loops

I am trying to convert a JSON string in a Javascript object literal. I think it is possible with some loops, but i couldn't get it done. The target structure is shown below, "chartData".

Fiddle can be found here: http://jsbin.com/ajemih/13/edit

Here's the JSON data:

```
{
   "1b":{
      "allLoad":"130",
      "loadMovement":"111",
      "allMovement":"111"
   },
   "1a":{
      "allLoad":"910",
      "loadMovement":"671",
      "allMovement":"280"
   },
   "systemLoad":"963"
}
```

This should it look like after the conversion:

```
chartData = [[['loadMovement', 111], 
              ['allMovement', 120], 
              ['allLoad', 130]], 
             [['Load+Move', 671], 
              ['allMovement', 280], 
              ['allLoad', 910]]];
```

Comment: The text of your question makes no sense.  There's no JSON string in either of your blocks of code.  Are you just asking how to convert the first javascript data structure to the second data structure?

Comment: Yes. I want to convert the first data structure in the second one.

Comment: @jfriend00 his first segment is technically valid JSON.  He's not using it that way in his fiddle though.

Comment: @mcknight you're going to have to be more specific about what rules you want to follow here.  Do you want to ignore values with primitive string keys? just ignore systemLoad?  Just traverse properties in the form 1<char> ?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? I couldn't find any actual attempted code in the jsbin.

Comment: @ben336 - JSON is a text format.  His first data structure is a javascript literal.

Comment: @jfriend00 in the fiddle yes.  But the code he shared here would be completely valid as a JSON file.  plug it into http://jsonlint.com/ 
I'm guessing he's probably parsing the JSON into an object form and working from that.  Regardless, its clear that what he actually wants is to convert the object form, not directly from JSON, so its just semantics.

Comment: @ben336 - it could be JSON if it was made into a string, but it isn't a string so it isn't JSON.  JSON is often misused as a descriptive term for a javascript literal which is what he appears to have here.

Comment: @jfriend00 it would also be JSON if it was in a text file, and he didn't want to put the parsing logic into the fiddle.  Regardless, I think we both know what JSON is and we're just arguing over semantics now.  I upvoted your answer and I'm moving on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this would work:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YmjDR/

```
var data = {
   "1b":{
      "allLoad":"130",
      "loadMovement":"111",
      "allMovement":"111"
   },
   "1a":{
      "allLoad":"910",
      "loadMovement":"671",
      "allMovement":"280"
   },
   "systemLoad":"963"
};

var chartData = [];

for (var i in data) {
    var item = data[i];
    var outer = [];
    // skip over items in the outer object that aren't nested objects themselves
    if (typeof item === "object") {
        for (var j in item) {
            var temp = [];
            temp.push(j);
            temp.push(item[j]);
            outer.push(temp);
        }
    }
    if (outer.length) {
        chartData.push(outer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
var chartData = []

for(var key in data) {        
    var properties = data[key];

    if(typeof properties === "object") {
       var array = [];

       for(var propKey in properties) {
           array.push([propKey, properties[propKey]])
       }

       chartData.push(array);
    }             
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aeuv5/1/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to map the data manually. Thats actually more a diligent but routine piece of work.

```
var jsonData = 'your json string';

Object.keys( jsonData ).map(function( key ) {
    if( typeof jsonData[ key ] === 'object' ) {
        return Object.keys( jsonData[ key ] ).sort(function( a, b ) {
            return +jsonData[ key ][ a ] - +jsonData[ key ][ b ];
        }).map(function( name ) {
            return [ name, jsonData[ key ][ name ] ];
        });
    }
}).filter( Boolean );
```

The above code will sort each group by its numeric value and then map a new array in the required style. Since `.map()` possibly returns `undefined` values on non-object elements, we need to filter those out before or afterwards.

See http://jsfiddle.net/WjZB2/2/

Comment: Just for the reference, the code can be way prettier: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/WjZB2/5/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. 
My goal was to convert a list of strings into a valid format for http://ivantage.github.io/angular-ivh-treeview/

This was my starting point:

```
[
  "A\\A1\\Test1",
  "A\\A1\\Test2",
  "A\\A2\\Test3",
  "B\\Test4",
  "B\\Test5",
  "B\\B1\\Test6",
  "B\\B1\\Test7",
  "B\\B1\\Test8",
  "C\\C1\\C1a\\Test9",
  "C\\C1\\C1b\\Test10",
  "C\\C2\\C2a\\Test11",
  "C\\C2\\C2a\\Test12",
  "C\\C2\\C2a\\Test13",
  "C\\C3\\Test14",
  "C\\Test15",
  "C\\Test16"
]
```

And I needed following format:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Selected Tests",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "A",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "A1",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Test1",
                "value": true
              },
              {
                "label": "Test2",
                "value": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "A2",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "Test3",
                "value": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

See my solution https://jsfiddle.net/ydt3gewn/